# Compile pjsip for JDK

Tags: java, swig, mingw32, pjsip

I am trying to compile pjsip 2.2.1 for desktop Java app

env:

```
Win7x64
MinGW32
JDK7
swig 3.0.0 (pre-built)
```

I have come so far as

```
$ ./configure
$ make dep && make clean && make
$ cd pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/
$ make
```

but after doing make I'm getting following error

```
mkdir -p output/org/pjsip/pjsua2
swig  -java  -package org.pjsip.pjsua2 \
                -outdir output/org/pjsip/pjsua2 \
                -o output/pjsua2_wrap.cpp ../pjsua2.i
..\pjsua2.i(82) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\types.hpp'
..\pjsua2.i(88) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\persistent.hpp'
..\pjsua2.i(90) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\siptypes.hpp'
..\pjsua2.i(101) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\media.hpp'
..\pjsua2.i(102) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\endpoint.hpp'
..\pjsua2.i(103) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\presence.hpp'
..\pjsua2.i(104) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\account.hpp'
..\pjsua2.i(105) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\call.hpp'
..\pjsua2.i(111) : Error: Unable to find 'pjsua2\json.hpp'
make: *** [output/pjsua2_wrap.cpp] Error 1
```

Unfortunately the pjsp doc does not contain any info about this. Please can anyone help..

### **UPDATE:**

Solved. Java build is dependent on Python so it MUST be installed.

```
$ ./configure
$ make dep && make clean && make
$ cd pjsip-apps/src/swig
$ make
```

Comment: Please post your edit as answer and accept it.

Comment: This way the .dll file was created? it is necessary to load pjsua2 library em windows right?